# Where / How to unit test and xstate guard function?

Tags: javascript, state-machine, xstate

I am using a guard function in my state machine.

```
const isDouble = (context, event) => {
  return context.num*2 === event.data.number
}
```

I would like to unit test this guard (I have simplified it for the purpose of the question) to assure that it works as intended always (prehaps someone will change the context structure, or the return from the server that brings about the data.number to the event etc.).

Where / How do I do that? Is there a regular pattern for this with xstate? Or should I just make a totally independent unit test where I want to?

Answer (score 0):

The guard should just be a pure function, so you can test it by providing test case data in the arguments:

```js
expect(isDouble(
  { num: 4 },
  { data: { number: 2 }
)).toBeTruthy();

expect(isDouble(
  { num: 5 },
  { data: { number: 2 }
)).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: But this would be an independet/external unit test right? I don't need to incorporate it directly in the state machine?